# optimization of bipartite graph

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph, bipartite

There are two sets one containing list of classes and other contains  list of teachers.Each teacher has a set of classes.We have to assign a teacher for a particular class such a way that number of classes engaged by teachers should be maximum.Is this problem is related to any optimization algorithm?I couldn't find any similar algorithms.Please help me to get the logic.

Thanks in advane

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you give a small example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [maximal matching problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29) that is [solveable efficiently in bipartite graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#Maximum_matchings_in_bipartite_graphs) using [maximal flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem) algorithms.

The reduction to the maximal flow is simple:

- Let your original graph be (V,U,E) [where V,U are the edges - one for
  'classes' and one for 'teachers' - the direction is teacher->class].
- Create a new graph G', with additional two vertices: `s,t`.
- Connect `s` to all teachers, and connect all classes to `t`.
- Give capacity of 1 for each edge in the new graph.
- Run maximal flow algorithm, that returns integer result (since the capacities are integers, it can be done).
- (profit)

Comment: we want find the maximum number of teachers assigned for taking classes!maximal flow algorithm is ok for that?

Comment: @user2877617 Wait, I may have misuderstood you - the solution I gave is correct if a teacher can teach ONLY one class. Is it the case? If not, I misunderstood and I will delete the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Graph Theory, what you need to find is the "maximum matching", the matching with the greatest number of edges. To find it there are several (but not many) algorithms. One of them is the Hopcroft-Karp, based on the technique of augmentation paths. Of course, it is recursive.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).